# Trouble shooting an error message. invalid/password

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I opened sqldeveloper and logged in to my the schemas I created, but I received an error message invalid username/password. The credentials are correct so I don't know why this is.

I uninstalled the Oracle 11g from my laptop and deleted the sqldeveloper folder. I re-installed the Oracle 11g and extracted the content of the sqldeveloper, double click on the sqldeveloper.exe file to open the sqldeveloper. I clicked to open a connection, entered password for the corresponding connection, but the problem remains the same.

An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
01017. 00000 -  "invalid username/password; logon denied"
*Cause:
*Action:
Vendor code 1017

I expected to be able to log in successfully because I used sqldeveloper 3 days ago and made changes to my computer.

Answer (score 3):

> The credentials are correct so I don't know why this is.

They are in fact, NOT correct, else you would be logged in.

The most likely causes of seeing this are:

1. you think you know the password, but you don't
2. you aren't logging into the right database
3. you're trying to log in as SYS w/o the AS SYSDBA clause

For the 2nd, this is more likely in 12c and higher in a Multitenant environment, where there is a CONTAINER and one or more PLUGGABLE databases. Make sure you're connected to the RIGHT instance - use the SERVICE NAME, not the SID in your connection definition.

Which would look like this in SQL Developer:
[image]

For the 3rd, if you're using something like SQL Developer, use this 
[image]